# HTML code gets displayed when it should not

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$obrazek = the_post_thumbnail( 'product_page_image' );
list($nic,$nic,$nic,$nic,$nic,$obrazeklink,$nic,$nic,$nic,$nic,$nic) = explode('"', $obrazek);
?>
```

and $obrazek variable contains

```
<img width="1560" height="1170" src="http://takopix.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/06/Melbourne-storm-1560x1170.jpg" class="attachment-product_page_image wp-post-image" alt="Melbourne storm">
```

but the HTML gets recognized even without echo... and explode doesn't work!

Comment: you either (1) didn't put it on a php server. (2) didn't go through the server to access it (i.e. like using a url `http://localhost/whatever.php` (3) didn't name the file as .php

Comment: Ok, looks like I was wrong. `$obrazek` is not hardcoded.  This is a wordpress thing. I've added that to the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [the_post_thumbnail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) is used to print the thumbnail markup. It returns nothing. You want [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)